# For interaction by other programs: command line, sockets, or something else?

Tags: sockets, command-line, sdk

I'm beginning an open-source project for logging work hours. The intention is to build something similar to Git, where instead of pushing code you're pushing information about work hours and progress.

I intend to make a PHP SDK for interaction with this program (and hopefully SDKs for other languages in the future), but I'm not sure how I should go about making this possible.

The SDK could make system() calls, but of course this has obvious security implications, portability issues, and I'm not sure what the *proper* way to do it is.

I'm also considering using a socket connection locally. My time management program would act as a server and then the SDK would establish a connection as the client. This seems the best to me so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a program to track hours, then don't write it as a standalone command-based utility for a single machine. Just don't. Really. Don't.

Instead write a REST server with authentication that can be reached from wherever you happen to be via our modern-day friend, the Internet. You can write the server in PHP if you'd like, or whatever you're comfortable with. But REST decouples your users and server. You might want a dedicated native mobile app for entering hours, and a single page web app for periodically generating invoices and reports, and a component part of a larger system that tracks hours as part of a large workforce. If you write it well, all of the implementations can use your server.

Don't think 'Git', think 'GitHub'. Write the REST back end that everyone can use with whatever front end a user might need. Write your utility to use the interface. But don't think small and write it to reside upon and serve a single machine - think big, about serving the whole planet.

Comment: The intention is to eventually be able to run this program as a server and have people "push" time information. Very similar to a Git repository, and I was thinking people would use a hosting provider (i.e. like GitHub with Git) to host time information.

What I missed in my explanation was that this program could be a client or a server, but on a local machine to frontend programs it would be a server.

However, I hadn't thought of using HTTP to communicate with the server. I don't think this would be necessary if I developed an SDK, but it's a great idea and I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: The way I'm thinking about this right now: my PHP SDK is what somebody would use to create a REST API for the server hosting time information. The time program itself (which I'm calling "Sit") will do its client-server communications over sockets I think. I'm considering native REST but I feel like that should be handled by existing webservers instead

Comment: No, the correct way really is to rewrite the program in PHP (or whatever language you want) and let a web server handle the hosting issues (although ASP.NET Core can self-host, which is an interesting scenario). An SDK won't solve your problems; adding socket communication to a console app to interface with an SDK just means you have two problems.

Comment: I don't agree that developing a web app instead of an application can be considered objectively "the correct way", but I don't think I was sufficiently clear about my intentions either. A web interface isn't a primary feature of this application - the primary purpose is to have a program similar to Git (in that a user has a local repository, and can push to a remote repository), but instead of pushing code you'd be pushing information about work hours and progress. The PHP SDK would be an extra (in a separate repo) to make it easy for web developers to access/change time information.